# How to get program to output a command to the ubuntu command line just as if i had typed it

Tags: command-line, python

I have a program dbot that works in the ubuntu command line. If from its directory called dbot I type into the command line from my keyboard " ./dbot.sh any command " it works and does what i want.

So this works ~/dbot$ ./dbot.sh anycommand

I am a beginner and have written a python 3 program tragic.py that is in the same directory called dbot.

If from the ubuntu command line I run tragic.py in the background by ~/dbot$ python3 tragic.py & then if I copy and paste ./dbot.sh anycommand then it works and dbot does what i want. It has to be in the background or the command will not work when pasted so I am using &.

However I want my python program tragic.py to print out onto the command line ./dbot.sh anycommand so that the command gets issued to dbot just as if I had typed it or pasted it. However it does not work either in the background or foreground.

I have tried using a normal print statement and sys.stdout.write() both with and with out sys.stdout.flush() but with no luck

How can I get dbot to respond to the command printed by tragic.py in the ubuntu command line. I dont understand why when I type it or paste it then it works but not when tragic.py prints it or outputs it with sys.stdout.write

Comment: Some options for accomplishing this with various tools are discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213821/53604).

Comment: Are you talking about [_Command Substitution_](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)? As in `./dbot.sh $(python3 tragic.py)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `xargs`, i.e.,

```
echo '-l' | xargs ls
```

will effectively execute `ls -l`. So in your case it should something like `./tragic.py | xargs ./dbot.sh`, i.e., output of `./tragic.py` command will be used as argument of `./dbot.sh`

Comment: Thanks for your help Jacek Herbrych - that is what i am looking for. I will give it a try! and thanks to John1024 and PerlDuck too.